# Can IIS 7 URL Rewrite Module rewrite outbound HTML loaded via AJAX?

Tags: ajax, iis-7, url-rewriting

The [IIS 7 URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) allows the [updating of URLs embedded in outbound HTML](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/657/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module/).

However, this does not work (at least for us) on outbound HTML loaded via AJAX.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this possible?